# Create XML request from each record of a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have tried many options including withColumn, udf, lambda, foreach, map but but not getting the expected output. At max, I am able to transform only the first record. The inputfile.json will keep on increasing and the expect op should give the xml in the desired structure. I will later on produce the expected op on Kafka.
Spark 2.3, Python 2.7. Need is to do in PySpark.

Edit 1:

I am able to add a column in the main dataframe which has the required xml. I used `withColumn` and `functions.format_string` and able to add strings(the xml structures) to columns of the dataframe.

Now my next target is to produce just the value of that new column to Kafka. I am using `df.foreachPartition(send_to_kafka)` and have created a function as below:

```
def send_to_kafka(rows):
    kafka = SimpleClient('localhost:9092')
    producer = SimpleProducer(kafka)
    for row in rows:
        producer.send_messages('test', str(row.asDict()))
```

But unfortunately it does two things:
a. Produces record on Kafka as `{'newColumn':u'myXMLPayload'}`. I do not want that. I want only `myXMLPayload` to be produced on Kafka.
b. It adds u' to the value for unicoding the value.

I want to get rid of these two parts and I would be good to go.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use the [structured streaming api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)?

Comment: probably use: `str(row.newColumn)` instead of `str(row.asDict())`

Comment: @jxc Getting                                                                                                          
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: newColumn

Comment: @cronoik getting:                                                  
                            pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"'writeStream' can be called only on streaming Dataset/Dataframe;"

Comment: @earl, what is the column name to save `xml`? isn't it `newColumn`

Comment: Yes. You are write. May be I was drunk when I tried that.....used newColumn now and it worked perfectly...thanks

Comment: @jxc how about sending entire row? As key:value where key is column name and value is its value and without encoding char u' ?

Comment: Although I am able to produce all the row on Kafka, the string columns' values are encoded with u' when I use asDict(). The int columns are fine..

Comment: @earl,  use `'{}:{}'.format('newColumn', row.newColumn)`, or just use `str()` function to convert the value's type from unicode into str.